# Azure AD login automatically for a specific user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm in the process of migrating an ASP.Net MVC app from windows authentication to Azure AD Authentication.

One of the requirements of the app is that some parts of it are accessed on a kiosk in a warehouse and it should auto-login to the web app. With windows authentication and the correct internet settings we can use the domain user to login without any prompt and the kiosk is then authenticated and has some specific roles to access only the parts of the app we`re interested in.

Is it possible to achieve the same result using Azure AD authentication, as in have a user logged in to a local AD, possibly to azure AD via powershell, automatically be logged in to an ASP.Net MVC app that uses Azure AD for authentication without any prompt?

I'm looking at any way to achieve the result of no login prompt for the kiosk user which is both in the local AD and azure AD.

Thanks